# How can i split a parameter in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, split

Hi Guys How can i split a parameter in plsql  purun_kod  is like 100,150,255,777 and i wanna split it and assign to v_urun_kod
thanks for your help.
My code is somewhat like:

```
function police_ara( purun_kod       in acente.levha_no%type,
                      ppolice_no      in varchar2) return sys_refcursor is
    vret sys_refcursor;
    v_urun_kod varchar(1000); 
  begin
    v_urun_kod := purun_kod;
  open vret for
      with policeler as
       (select distinct ph.police_hareket_id ph_police_hareket_id,
                        p.urun_kod
                        (select max(pho.police_hareket_id) from police_hareket_otr pho
            where pho.police_hareket_id = ph.police_hareket_id
           and (pho.durum_kod1 = 0 or pho.durum_kod2 = 0 or pho.durum_kod3 = 0 or pho.durum_kod4 = 0)) pho_police_hareket_id,

                        ph.odeme_arac_kod,
                        ph.police_id
         from police p
         inner join police_hareket ph
           and (ph.ekbelge_no>0 or (select count(1)
                  from police_kotasyon pk
                 where pk.police_hareket_id = ph.police_hareket_id 
                   and pk.kotasyon_seviyesi = 3
                   and rownum = 1)>0)
          left join police_prim pp
            on (pp.police_hareket_id = ph.police_hareket_id and pp.para_birim_kod = ph.para_birim_kod)
          left join musteri_rol mr
            on (mr.musteri_rol_id = pa.acente_id)
         where (p.urun_kod = purun_kod or purun_kod is null)
         and(p.police_no = ppolice_no or ppolice_no is null)

      select urun_kod,
             acente_kod,
             brut_prim
        from policeler
        left join police_musteri pm_sg
          on pm_sg.police_hareket_id = ph_police_hareket_id
         and pm_sg.rol_id = pck_const_rol.sigortali
         and pm_sg.sira_no = 1
        left join musteri m_sg
          on (m_sg.musteri_id = pm_sg.musteri_id)
       order by police_id;
    return vret;
  end;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to split a comma-separated values string into rows. It is a SQL*Plus example, just to show how it works:

```
SQL> var purun_kod varchar2(100);
SQL> exec :purun_kod := '100,150,255,777';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select regexp_substr(:purun_kod, '[^,]+', 1, level) urun_kod
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= regexp_count(:purun_kod, ',') + 1;

URUN_KOD
----------------------------------------------------------------------
100
150
255
777

SQL>
```

---

Currently, code you posted doesn't make much sense as you never use `v_urun_kod`. As the function returns ref cursor, there's no much sense in running that code for each separate value; you *might* do that in a loop, but that wouldn't work as you'd want it to (at least, I think so).

Looking at it, I guess that something like this might do what you're looking for:

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  function police_ara( purun_kod       in varchar2,
  3                       ppolice_no      in varchar2)
  4  return sys_refcursor is
  5    vret          sys_refcursor;
  6    -- v_urun_kod varchar(1000);   --> no need for that variable any more
  7  begin
  8    open vret for
  9      with policeler as
 10        (select distinct ph.police_hareket_id ph_police_hareket_id,
 11                         p.urun_kod,
 12                         (select max(pho.police_hareket_id)
 13                          from police_hareket_otr pho
 14                          where pho.police_hareket_id = ph.police_hareket_id
 15                            and (   pho.durum_kod1 = 0
 16                                 or pho.durum_kod2 = 0
 17                                 or pho.durum_kod3 = 0
 18                                 or pho.durum_kod4 = 0
 19                                )
 20                         ) pho_police_hareket_id,
 21                         --
 22                         ph.odeme_arac_kod,
 23                         ph.police_id
 24           from police p
 25           --> this is new
 26           join (select regexp_substr(purun_kod, '[^,]+', 1, level) urun_kod
 27                 from dual
 28                 connect by level <= regexp_count(purun_kod, ',') + 1
 29                ) x on x.urun_kod = p.urun_kod
 30           --> end of "this is new"
 31           inner join police_hareket ph on 1 = 1 --> you're missing join condition here
 32             and (   ph.ekbelge_no > 0
 33                  or (select count(1)
 34                      from police_kotasyon pk
 35                      where pk.police_hareket_id = ph.police_hareket_id
 36                        and pk.kotasyon_seviyesi = 3
 37                        and rownum = 1
 38                     ) > 0
 39                 )
 40            left join police_prim pp
 41              on (    pp.police_hareket_id = ph.police_hareket_id
 42                  and pp.para_birim_kod = ph.para_birim_kod
 43                 )
 44            left join musteri_rol mr
 45              on (mr.musteri_rol_id = pa.acente_id)
 46           where (   p.urun_kod = purun_kod
 47                  or purun_kod is null
 48                 )
 49             and (   p.police_no = ppolice_no
 50                  or ppolice_no is null
 51                 )
 52        )
 53        select urun_kod,
 54               acente_kod,
 55               brut_prim
 56          from policeler
 57          left join police_musteri pm_sg
 58            on pm_sg.police_hareket_id = ph_police_hareket_id
 59           and pm_sg.rol_id = pck_const_rol.sigortali
 60           and pm_sg.sira_no = 1
 61          left join musteri m_sg
 62            on (m_sg.musteri_id = pm_sg.musteri_id)
 63         order by police_id;
 64    return vret;
 65  end;
 66  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.
```

Pay attention to the following:

- line 6: there's no need for `v_urun_kod` variable any more
- lines 25 - 30: this is a new piece of code which utilizes the above posted example. That `SELECT` is used as an inline view and joined with the `police` table's `urun_kod` column (at least, that's what I think you should do)
- line 31: you're missing the `ON` clause here; fix it yourself, I don't know what should that be
- the function is created with compilation errors as I don't have your tables; other than that, it *might* be OK:

  ```
  SQL> show err
  Errors for FUNCTION POLICE_ARA:

  LINE/COL ERROR
  -------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
  8/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
  43/21    PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
  SQL>
  ```

Comment: thanks for your replay but ```join (select regexp_substr(purun_kod, '[^,]+', 1, level) urun_kod
                 from dual
                  connect by level <= regexp_count(purun_kod, ',') + 1
                ) x on x.urun_kod = p.urun_kod``` this code is not make split it is same urun_kod same 156,233,445

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, I don't understand what you are trying to say. Code I posted *splits* comma-separated values into rows. What will you do with it later, it is up to you. I tried to write some code that I *thought* might be what you are looking for. If it is not, feel free to use it the best you can